# How can I read the BCM/UCH data from the car via OBD?

Tags: bluetooth, can-bus, obd-ii

I am trying to read the data related to Body of the car, like if doors are unlocked/locked, if the seat belts are on, odometer reading etc.

I am successfully able to read the ECU data via VGATE (ELM327) bluetooth OBD2 adapter.
But I can only read the Speed and RPM etc.

I also want to perform the write operations like locking/unlocking car. Is there any way to make this happen? If not possible with ELM 327 than what is the other adapter i can use?

Comment: What's the make/model of the car?

Comment: Renault Duster RxZ (Diesel)

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on the car.  Most of those operations in modern cars is done via CAN, ELM327 cannot keep up with most of the CAN networks in cars.  An OBDLink SX is cheap and capable of the speeds required for CAN.  You'll probably want to monitor the CAN and see if there even is messages to unlock and lock.  Much of what you want to do is only done by dealer software, so you'll need to get that for your car and slowly reverse engineer it.

Answer (score 1):

Applications such as locking doors, opening windows, and some of the controls on the steering wheel such as left and right turn signals are commonly found on another vehicle communication protocol called LIN. Wikipedia does a great job explaining LIN https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network.

In some ways, it is similar to CAN, and is used because it is cheaper to implement this single-wired communication protocol than the two-wired communication of CAN.

The LIN bus isn't accessible via the ODBII port under most steering wheels, so it will have to be accessed via other vehicle instrumentation such as the radio or around the center console. Here's a link to someone who has managed to get into the LIN bus http://hackaday.com/2014/04/19/a-lin-bus-signal-injector/.